# List all nodes in a Liquid Template?

Tags: ruby, liquid

Considering the following parsed template and a loop to its root.nodelist:

```
text = '{% if true %}{{ "poland" | capitalize }}{% else %}{{ "portugal" | capitalize}}{% endif %}'
template = Liquid::Template.parse(text)
template.root.nodelist.each { |node| p node }
```

will print only:

```
Portugal
```

(and not Poland)

How could one list all nodes (including Liquid variables, tags, etc) from a template? Especially those inside if/else logic?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really able to find a direct way to access Blocks in a condition, but I used a workaround to add a method to the Class with the following code

```
def b
  @blocks
end
```

And then using this code

```
template.root.nodelist[0].b.each { |a| p a.attachment[0].name }
```

I could find the list you are looking for